# Perfect display data append to xml file using PHP

Tags: php, xml

file xml:

```
<albums>
   <album>
      <name>My Album 1</name>
      <created>2014-05-14</created>
   </album>
</albums>
```

when i append data to file, result look like this:

```
<albums>
   <album>
      <name>My Album 1</nam>
      <created>2014-05-15</created>
   </album><album><name>My Album 2</name><created>2014-05-15</created></album></albums>
```

i want result look like:

```
 <albums>
       <album>
          <name>My Album 1</nam>
          <created>2014-05-15</created>
       </album>
       <album>
           <name>My Album 2</name>
           <created>2014-05-15</created>
       </album>
   </albums>
```

how i can do this?

Comment: Use a DOM parser. Unless you're very careful, doing string manipulations on the raw xml document-as-string will probably just corrupt it.

Comment: How do you append data now? A code sample would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following before your XML in php and it will align accordingly

```
header('Content-type:text/xml');
```